# Where is schema location of spring for apache ftp?

Tags: spring, apache, ftp, ftp-server

I cant find spring namespace for apache ftp `http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1` this link does not works.....what is alternante link..?

here is `ftpd-typical.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--
        Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
        contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with
        this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
        The ASF licenses this file to you under the Apache License, Version
        2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
        with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required by
        applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
        License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR
        CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for
        the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the
        License.
    -->
<server xmlns="http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1  http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/ftpserver-1.0.xsd"
    id="myServer">
    <listeners>
        <nio-listener name="default" port="2121">
            <ssl>
                <keystore file="./res/ftpserver.jks" password="password" />
            </ssl>
        </nio-listener>
    </listeners>
    <file-user-manager file="./res/conf/users.properties" />

    <ftplets>
        <ftplet name="myftplet">
            <beans:bean class="ftplettest.MyFtplet"></beans:bean>
        </ftplet>
    </ftplets>
</server>
```

I am getting following error :

```
C:\Apache FTP Server\ftpserver-1.0.6\apache-ftpserver-1.0.6\bin>ftpd.bat res/conf/ftpd-typical.xml
Using XML configuration file res/conf/ftpd-typical.xml...
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 30 in XML document from file [C:\Apache FTP Server\ftpserver-1.0.6\apache-ftpserver-1.0.6
\res\conf\ftpd-typical.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 30; columnNumber: 11; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content
was found starting with element 'ftplets'. One of '{"http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1":native-filesystem, "http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1":file
system, "http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1":commands, "http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1":messages}' is expected.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:113)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:80)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
        at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
        at org.apache.ftpserver.main.CommandLine.getConfiguration(CommandLine.java:132)
        at org.apache.ftpserver.main.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:56)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 30; columnNumber: 11; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ftplets'. One of
 '{"http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1":native-filesystem, "http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1":filesystem, "http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/
v1":commands, "http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1":messages}' is expected.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:449)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3228)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1787)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:376)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2715)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:240)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
        ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error for normal java app -not Spring-, too.But I overcome with some changes.You should be carefull to configuration file.
(ftpd-full.xml).If you have a package name in your java class, you shoud write "bean:class" property with your package name in ftpd-full.xml file .My conf file (ftpd-full.xml) is like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<server xmlns="http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
    http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1 http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/ftpserver-1.0.xsd 
    "
 id="myServer"> 
 <listeners>
  <nio-listener name="default" port="2222" implicit-ssl="false"
   idle-timeout="60"  >
   <ssl>
                <keystore file="./res/ftpserver.jks" password="password" />
            </ssl>   
   <blacklist>1.2.3.0/16, 1.2.4.0/16, 1.2.3.4</blacklist>
  </nio-listener>
 </listeners> 
 <ftplets>
  <ftplet name="ftplet1">
   <beans:bean class="MyFtplet">

   </beans:bean>
  </ftplet>
 </ftplets>
 <!-- The user manager, choose one -->
 <file-user-manager file="./res/conf/users.properties"
  encrypt-passwords="true" /> 
 <!-- The file system -->
 <native-filesystem case-insensitive="false"
  create-home="true" /> 
 <!-- Define the available languages -->
 <messages languages="en" />
</server>
```

Maybe, it helps you to organize your file, too.
With kind regards.

Comment: Thanks to your tip, I got the server up and running and spotted the config bug

Answer (score 0):

use

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1 
 http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/ftpserver-1.0.xsd  
"
```

instead of

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1 
 https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/ftpserver-1.0.xsd  
"
```

full example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<server xmlns="http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1 
 http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/ftpserver-1.0.xsd  
 "
id="myServer">
<listeners>
<nio-listener name="default" port="2121">
    <ssl>
            <keystore file="./res/ftpserver.jks" password="password" />
        </ssl>
  </nio-listener>
  </listeners>
  <file-user-manager file="./res/conf/users.properties" />
</server>
```